# Script terminates when storing grep -c output when value is 0

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to check if a file has CR line feed and store the result 0 or 1 into a variable.

Here is my command that runs inside a script.

```
isCR="$(file ${fileName} | grep -c 'with CR line terminators')"
```

The script runs until the previous line and doesn't run this line but terminates abruptly.

Inside an echo statement it works perfectly.

```
echo "isCR=$(file ${fileName} | grep -c 'with CR line terminators')"
```

This prints isCR=0 or isCR=1 depending on the file I use.

But just storing the value into variable isCR doesn't work. I am confused what am i missing here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try dropping the quotes?

Comment: Tried both dropping '' and replacing single quotes with double quotes.
Looks like the issue is with multiple words in grep. if I check grep for CR then it works. But more than a word doesn't work

Comment: I think you can execute within backticks also

Comment: Please describe **how** *storing the value into variable isCR doesn't work* ... it works fine here.

Comment: "The script runs until the previous line and doesn't run this line but terminates abruptly"? Eh? How do you *know* it doesn't run that line? Don't describe your interpretation of it; describe the *immediate symptom itself*.

Comment: Running `bash -x yourscript` to log lines as they run is likely to be helpful.

Comment: The echo statement after isCR="$(file ${fileName} | grep -c 'with CR line terminators')" doesn't get printed

Comment: BTW, `file ${fileName}` is generally buggy -- it'll mishandle names with spaces or glob characters. Use `file "$fileName"` or `file "${fileName}"`, and see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: @dreddy, ...what echo statement? You haven't shown us one. Please provide a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code that can be copied-and-pasted with no changes or additions to let someone else observe the problem on their own machine.

Comment: isCR="$(file ${fileName} | grep -c 'with CR line terminators')" 
When isCR=1 it runs, when it is zero it doesn't run the subsequent commands in the script

Comment: Let me guess, you're using `set -e`? **Don't.** (at least, not without reading [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises)).

Comment: a=$(file "${fileName}" | grep -c 'ASCII text')
echo "a: $a"
This prints $a value
a=$(file "${fileName}" | grep -c 'Wrong Input ASCII text')
echo "a: $a"
This doesn't print $a value

Comment: In a shell that's configured according to defaults, those lines **do** print values. You need to have a nondefault configuration like `set -e` to get the behavior described.

Comment: (some tools like Jenkins "helpfully" turn `set -e` on by default without it being explicitly requested; I wonder if you're in that kind of context).

Comment: See https://ideone.com/WUUmGL -- you can see it does indeed print `a: 0`.

Comment: ...that said, for your actual use case I would advise not using `grep` at all, as bash's string-manipulation primitives suffice for the task. `if [[ "$(file "$fileName")" =~ 'with CR line terminators' ]]; then ...`

Comment: ...or, as an even faster way to run the same test without even requiring `file`, you can just look for a carriage return at the end of the first line: `IFS= read -r firstLine <"$fileName"; if [[ $firstLine = *$'\r' ]]; then ...`

Comment: If you want to test whether `set -e` is use, run `echo "$-"` -- if the output contains an `e` character, you're running in the `errexit` mode previously described. This mode can be disabled using the command `set +e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `set -e` (aka `set -o errexit`) tells the shell to exit whenever any command returns a nonzero exit status.

`grep` returns a nonzero exit status when it finds no matches.

Thus, when using `bash -e`, `set -e`, `set -o errexit`, an `ERR` trap which triggers an exit, or similar configuration, `isCR="$(file ${fileName} | grep -c 'with CR line terminators')"` will terminate your script because the nonzero exit status from the `grep` command is passed through as the exit status of the command as a whole.

By contrast, `echo "$(false)"` does not because its exit status is that of `echo`, not that of `false`; this holds true when the command returning the failed exit status is `grep` as well.

---

If you want to use `set -e` but bypass its behavior for this specific line, consider:

```
isCR="$(file ${fileName} | grep -c 'with CR line terminators')" || [[ $isCR ]]
```

The `|| [[ $isCR ]]` will make the line as a whole have a truthy result even if `grep` returns false, so long as it emitted a nonzero number of characters.

Comment: `if isCR=$(...); then ...` is another way to fix this issue, since branching on a command's exit status flags it as "checked", suppressing `set -e` behavior. (Even more confusingly, branching on a function's exit status suppresses `set -e` for the whole of the function, and every other function *it* calls in turn).